# How can I transfer the users from an old mysql install with having access to ONLY the physical files?

Tags: permissions, 15.04, filesystem, mysql, data-recovery

So, I had crashed my server into a non-bootable state. I reinstalled, but not before grabbing the /etc,/usr, and /var directories. I reinstalled mysql on the new install, and was able to copy the old databases from the old physical db files. But it won't let me just replace the mysql database, as it tells me that the 'user' table is marked bad and should be repaired. Is there any way I can recover the users from those files?
System Specs.
My old OS was Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn)
My New OS is Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet)
I don't know what version sql was installed on the old installation and I think 5.6 is running on the new install.

Answer (score 0):

ANOTHER QUESTION I FIGURED OUT!!! First, I renamed the folder of the old mysql folder with the database files. Then, I copied it to the server, reloaded phpmyadmin and the new database was there, I then exported the user table and imported it to the new user table. And Voila! My old users were transfered!